# use PBKDF2 with openssl in bash instead of php

Tags: openssl, cryptography, pbkdf2

I have this script in php but I want to use that in bash.
I don't understand if i can do that in openssl or I  Have to install something through brew.

```
<?
$password = "army van defense carry jealous true garbage claim echo media make crunch";
$iterations = 2048;
$salt="mnemonic";
$hash = hash_pbkdf2("sha512", $password, $salt, $iterations);
echo $hash;
```

I tried with

```
printf "army van defense carry jealous true garbage claim echo media make crunch" | openssl dgst -sha512 -hmac "mnemonic"
```

But I don't have derivation function before

Comment: Therefore you are searching for a tool that implements BIP-0039.

Comment: AFAIK the PBKDF2 functionality (which is part of password based encryption, or PBE) is implemented in OpenSSL, but it isn't directly available through the command line.